# Compiling boost with MPI and python

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

I am having some trouble compiling boost with the MPI and python libraries enabled.  Here is the error:

```
libs/mpi/src/python/py_nonblocking.cpp: In function 'bool {anonymous}::wrap_test_all({anonymous}::request_list&, boost::python::api::object)':
libs/mpi/src/python/py_nonblocking.cpp:167:63: error: cannot convert 'boost::optional<{anonymous}::py_call_output_iterator<boost::mpi::status, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<boost::mpi::python::request_with_value*, std::vector<boost::mpi::python::request_with_value> > > >' to 'bool' in return
       status_value_iterator(py_callable, requests.begin()));
```

I am using gcc version 4.9.2 (Homebrew gcc49 4.9.2).  Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself; looks like there was a bug.

https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/10282